# Keep Original Sorting of Labels in Excel Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of projects and the quarter that they are to be completed in. I used this data to create a PivotTable that puts a "1" under the column for the quarter when the project is to be completed.

How can I keep the sorting of the projects from the original table where they are listed by quarter, then by name?

My real data is being pulled from a SharePoint 2013 list and displayed in an Excel web part on the site, so I can't change it to manipulate the names and there could be more projects added at any time.

[image: Source Data and Pivot Table]

Answer (score 1):

There is one option that I can think of which works just out-of-the-box and it's explained by Microsoft in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235537/en-us). The trick is to create a *[custom field](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4)* and use that as a sorting key. A custom field is an ordered list, such as the days of the week or the months of the year.

One significant disadvantage of this method is that it does not automatically handle new items in your list. In your example: if there is a new project, you'll have to re-create the custom list with the new item in it.

I'll walk you through it (since you don't state the version of Excel you're using, I'll follow the default menu's for my version, which is Excel 2010):

- Go to `File`, `Options`, `Advanced` and all the way at the bottom click `Edit Custom Lists...`
- In the 'Import list from cells' input box, select the original list of projects (A2..A7 in your example) and click `Import` and click `OK`. Now exit the options dialog.
- In the sorting options of the project field in the Pivot table, select `More sort options...` and click `More options...` in the next dialog. Deselect the checkbox at the top and select the custom list in the dropdown (`First key sort order`) and click `OK` twice.

Comment: Thanks, but the pivot table is going to live in an Excel web part, so I need it to handle new items automatically.

Comment: Is it possible in your scenario to use Power Query? In that case, you could add an incementing index, and sort on the minimum value of that index and make that value invisible in the resulting pivot table.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in Excel 2010 (Version 14.0.7252.500 (32-bit)). I can add Custom List, but the pivot table doesn't get sorted.